# The Next tag badge block overlaps other block on user's Profile Activity page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, user-interface

The Next tag badge block overlaps the badge score block.

[image]

Comment: To be more obvious don’t forget to add freehand red circles on the image.

Comment: Is anyone tracking a tag badge for [SO's longest tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/896629/longest-tag), [visual-studio-app-center-distribute]?